# Is there any known documentation about Microsoft pinging Azure Worker Role Ports?

Tags: azure, azure-worker-roles

I have an Azure Worker Role and it listens for requests on a port.  Multiple Microsoft owned IP's ping that socket every 4-17 seconds non stop.  It looks like they drop the connection causing errors in my application.  I only noticed it now with some personal logging turned on.

Has anyone heard of microsoft pinging your open ports?

The source IP's are

- 40.122.64.23
- 168.62.68.118

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure employs the mechanism called network probes to identify the health of the deployments. I think that what you see is the behavior of that service.

"Guest agent probe (on PaaS VMs only). Azure Load Balancer utilizes the guest agent inside the virtual machine. It listens and responds with an HTTP 200 OK response only when the instance is in the Ready state (i.e. the instance is not in a state like Busy, Recycling, or Stopping). If the guest agent fails to respond with an HTTP 200 OK, Azure Load Balancer marks the instance as unresponsive and stops sending traffic to that instance. Load Balancer will continue to ping the instance." From [documentation](https://github.com/Azure/azure-content/blob/master/articles/load-balancer/load-balancer-overview.md).

You can ask technical support as well for identify who are those guys.

Comment: This also occurs on tcp endpoints setup through InstanceInputEndpoint on a cloud service. Every 10 seconds! Yet there is no documentation on how to configure the probe on such endpoints only for InputEndpoint.

Comment: Documentation seems to be wrong, I have no custom load balancer probe defined yet every endpoint is being probed, including TCP, documentation states that only the Guest Agent will be probed for webroles.. Please document this as it is causing errors on my endpoints. The IP from the connecting probe changed it is now 168.62.68.119 .. is there a listing of IPs used by the probe?

Comment: @mms that is weird. I believe there is no such list of IPs, as they are dynamically changing. Maybe you could use something like a Microsoft Network Monitor or WireShark to see what is going on with these packets? Or you sure that it is the simple ping?

Comment: weird indeed, the fact there is no real documentation for this is even weirder. Getting pings every 10 seconds on all the tcp endpoints on the webrole from 40.122.64.23  and 168.62.68.119 .. these are Microsoft IPs yet they are not from my roles..

Comment: @mms let me check please and i will return.

Comment: @mms still checking - one suggestion was to try to delete and create the endpoint and see if the traffic from these endpoints will go. The question again what is the nature of that traffic - simple ICMP (ping) should hit very hard to make the endpoint unavailable. Can you try to catch some of these packets and paste somewhere?